# How to make label backgrounds transparent in SWT

Tags: java, swt

I'm pretty new to java SWT, and while putting labels, it looks like i can't make the label background transparent. I'm using eclipse luna SWT desine form.
this is what my window looks like:
[image]

as you can see,all the label backgrounds are white.
What should i do so the label backgrounds will be the same as the window background(grey) by default (meaning - not by changing each label background at runtime, which does work for me).

it probably simple, but i just couldn't find on google how  to do it. 
here is my code:

```
   import java.awt.Color;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.FormToolkit;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.DataBindingContext;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.IObservableValue;
import org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.WidgetProperties;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans.PojoProperties;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm;
import org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.SWTObservables;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;


public class WinApp2 {
    private DataBindingContext m_bindingContext;

    protected Shell shell;
    private Text destenation_ip;
    private final FormToolkit formToolkit = new FormToolkit(Display.getDefault());
    private Label lblDestenationPortIp;
    private Label lblNewLabel;
    private Text ammount_of_packets;
    private Label lblNewLabel_1;
    private Text sorce_ip;
    private Text destenation_port;
    private Text sorce_port;
    private Label lblNewLabel_2;
    private Label label;
    private Label label_1;
    private Label ammount_of_packets_info;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Realm.runWithDefault(SWTObservables.getRealm(display), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    WinApp2 window = new WinApp2();
                    window.open();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);
        shell.setSize(450, 306);
        shell.setText("LAN Destroyer");
        shell.setLayout(new FormLayout());
        destenation_ip = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        FormData fd_destenation_ip = new FormData();
        destenation_ip.setLayoutData(fd_destenation_ip);

        lblDestenationPortIp = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblDestenationPortIp.setAlignment(SWT.RIGHT);
        FormData fd_lblDestenationPortIp = new FormData();
        fd_lblDestenationPortIp.left = new FormAttachment(0, 351);
        fd_lblDestenationPortIp.right = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
        fd_lblDestenationPortIp.top = new FormAttachment(0, 35);
        lblDestenationPortIp.setLayoutData(fd_lblDestenationPortIp);
        lblDestenationPortIp.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_LIST_SELECTION_TEXT));
        formToolkit.adapt(lblDestenationPortIp, true, true);
        lblDestenationPortIp.setText(":\u05E9\u05DC \u05D9\u05E2\u05D3 IP");

        lblNewLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel.setAlignment(SWT.RIGHT);
        FormData fd_lblNewLabel = new FormData();
        fd_lblNewLabel.right = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
        lblNewLabel.setLayoutData(fd_lblNewLabel);
        formToolkit.adapt(lblNewLabel, true, true);
        lblNewLabel.setText(":\u05DB\u05DE\u05D5\u05EA");

        ammount_of_packets = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        fd_destenation_ip.left = new FormAttachment(ammount_of_packets, 0, SWT.LEFT);
        fd_destenation_ip.right = new FormAttachment(ammount_of_packets, -1, SWT.RIGHT);
        FormData fd_ammount_of_packets = new FormData();
        fd_ammount_of_packets.right = new FormAttachment(lblNewLabel, -68);
        fd_ammount_of_packets.top = new FormAttachment(lblNewLabel, -3, SWT.TOP);
        ammount_of_packets.setLayoutData(fd_ammount_of_packets);
        formToolkit.adapt(ammount_of_packets, true, true);

        Button nonstop_send = new Button(shell, SWT.CHECK);
        fd_ammount_of_packets.left = new FormAttachment(0, 186);
        nonstop_send.setAlignment(SWT.RIGHT);
        nonstop_send.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                if(nonstop_send.getSelection()){
                    ammount_of_packets_info.setText("שולח ללא הפסקה");
                    ammount_of_packets_info.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GREEN));
                    ammount_of_packets.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else {
                    ammount_of_packets_info.setText("");
                    ammount_of_packets.setEnabled(true);
                }

            }
        });
        FormData fd_nonstop_send = new FormData();
        fd_nonstop_send.top = new FormAttachment(lblNewLabel, 0, SWT.TOP);
        fd_nonstop_send.right = new FormAttachment(ammount_of_packets, -9);
        nonstop_send.setLayoutData(fd_nonstop_send);
        formToolkit.adapt(nonstop_send, true, true);
        nonstop_send.setText("\u05E9\u05DC\u05D7 \u05DC\u05DC\u05D0 \u05D4\u05E4\u05E1\u05E7\u05D4");

        lblNewLabel_1 = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        fd_lblNewLabel.top = new FormAttachment(lblNewLabel_1, 6);
        lblNewLabel_1.setAlignment(SWT.RIGHT);
        FormData fd_lblNewLabel_1 = new FormData();
        fd_lblNewLabel_1.right = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
        fd_lblNewLabel_1.top = new FormAttachment(lblDestenationPortIp, 6);
        lblNewLabel_1.setLayoutData(fd_lblNewLabel_1);
        formToolkit.adapt(lblNewLabel_1, true, true);
        lblNewLabel_1.setText(":\u05E9\u05DC \u05DE\u05E7\u05D5\u05E8 IP");

        sorce_ip = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        fd_destenation_ip.bottom = new FormAttachment(sorce_ip);
        fd_lblNewLabel_1.left = new FormAttachment(sorce_ip, 29);
        FormData fd_sorce_ip = new FormData();
        fd_sorce_ip.top = new FormAttachment(0, 58);
        fd_sorce_ip.left = new FormAttachment(0, 186);
        fd_sorce_ip.right = new FormAttachment(100, -114);
        sorce_ip.setLayoutData(fd_sorce_ip);
        formToolkit.adapt(sorce_ip, true, true);

        destenation_port = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        fd_nonstop_send.left = new FormAttachment(destenation_port, 0, SWT.LEFT);
        FormData fd_destenation_port = new FormData();
        fd_destenation_port.top = new FormAttachment(0, 32);
        fd_destenation_port.left = new FormAttachment(0, 40);
        destenation_port.setLayoutData(fd_destenation_port);
        formToolkit.adapt(destenation_port, true, true);

        sorce_port = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        sorce_port.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN));
        sorce_port.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW));
        FormData fd_sorce_port = new FormData();
        fd_sorce_port.top = new FormAttachment(lblNewLabel_1, -3, SWT.TOP);
        fd_sorce_port.left = new FormAttachment(destenation_port, 0, SWT.LEFT);
        sorce_port.setLayoutData(fd_sorce_port);
        formToolkit.adapt(sorce_port, true, true);

        lblNewLabel_2 = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        FormData fd_lblNewLabel_2 = new FormData();
        fd_lblNewLabel_2.top = new FormAttachment(0, 35);
        fd_lblNewLabel_2.left = new FormAttachment(destenation_port, 6);
        lblNewLabel_2.setLayoutData(fd_lblNewLabel_2);
        formToolkit.adapt(lblNewLabel_2, true, true);
        lblNewLabel_2.setText(":\u05E4\u05D5\u05E8\u05D8");

        label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText(":\u05E4\u05D5\u05E8\u05D8");
        FormData fd_label = new FormData();
        fd_label.bottom = new FormAttachment(nonstop_send, -6);
        fd_label.left = new FormAttachment(sorce_port, 6);
        label.setLayoutData(fd_label);
        formToolkit.adapt(label, true, true);

        label_1 = new Label(shell, SWT.WRAP | SWT.SHADOW_IN);
        FormData fd_label_1 = new FormData();
        fd_label_1.top = new FormAttachment(ammount_of_packets, 20);
        fd_label_1.left = new FormAttachment(0, 187);
        label_1.setLayoutData(fd_label_1);
        formToolkit.adapt(label_1, true, true);
        label_1.setText(":\u05E1\u05D9\u05DB\u05D5\u05DD");

        ammount_of_packets_info = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        ammount_of_packets_info.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_MAGENTA));
        FormData fd_ammount_of_packets_info = new FormData();
        fd_ammount_of_packets_info.left = new FormAttachment(100, -158);
        fd_ammount_of_packets_info.top = new FormAttachment(ammount_of_packets, 44);
        fd_ammount_of_packets_info.right = new FormAttachment(100, -36);
        ammount_of_packets_info.setLayoutData(fd_ammount_of_packets_info);
        formToolkit.adapt(ammount_of_packets_info, true, true);
        m_bindingContext = initDataBindings();

    }
    protected DataBindingContext initDataBindings() {
        DataBindingContext bindingContext = new DataBindingContext();
        //
        return bindingContext;
    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: You can set the background to be transparent `(shell.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);`).

Comment: where in the code should i add it?

Comment: Anywhere after you make the shell. This will just make it so that any label will have the background of the shell unless you explicitly tell it otherwise. See the example below for an alternative solution (I commented out `shell.setBackground()` but you can use that instead of setting the text to null. Good luck with your project. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is caused by `FormToolkit#adapt(Control, boolean, boolean)`. Internally, this method sets the background color to the background color of the toolkit.

You can prevent that by calling:

```
formToolkit.setBackground(null);
```

---

Reference: [Source of `FormToolkit#adapt(Control, boolean, boolean)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6/org.eclipse.ui/forms/3.5.0/org/eclipse/ui/forms/widgets/FormToolkit.java#FormToolkit.adapt%28org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Composite%29)

Comment: Dammm! You actually read through all of that code. Good for you, and nice spot.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to have text, use the what I mentioned above: `shell.setBackground(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);`. This makes it so that the background of your label will match the background color.

However, you can also do a simpler option. If you want to "hide" text, yet need to keep it for later and display it when you want to, you can set the text of a particular label to be `null`.

I often use this when I need text to disappear. The only thing is, is you need to store the text into an array (list) - or whatever you want (i.e. a database or someting similar) so you can save the text for later. You don't even need to use `SWT.INHERIT_FORCE`.This is a full example that might help:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;


/**
 *
 * @author Dylan
 */

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        shell.setText("Stackoverflow Test");

        shell.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
//        shell.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);

        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("Button that's fun to click - but there is no text :D");
        Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("Horray, you entered text to stdin!!");

        ArrayList<String> labelText = new ArrayList<>();
        labelText.add(label.getText());
        label.setText("");

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();

        Boolean flag = false;
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
                if (!flag) {
                    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter some text");
                        char[] cbuf = new char[40];

                        String text = reader.readLine();

                        if (text.length()> 0) {
                            flag = true;

                            label.setText(labelText.remove(0));
                            button.setText(button.getText() + "... and now there is. Yay!");
                            shell.pack();
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException io) {
                        System.err.println(io.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a slightly poor example because the `BufferedReader` locks up the screen until the user enters input. It would be better if the input was entered into the shell or if there was a thread.

Comment: adding shell.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE); didn't help... i pasted it all over the code a few time and it didn't affect anything.

Comment: @user3013996 Try putting this after `Display display = Display.getDefault();` in your `open()` method... `Shell shell = new Shell(display);`. This gives you a shell object that you can do whatever you want with (which allows you to do `shell.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);` **after** you make the shell object).

Comment: Well, I guess you do that in `createContents()`. Sorry, I did not see that. You have to pass the display into the shell, though. You have `Shell shell = new Shell(/*pass in display here*/);` (without the comments, of course). This means that the easier ways are to have them in the same method or to use a class variable (which you have)
.

Comment: i added what you said, but its still is not working.. :( here is my code:     `public void open() {
  Display display = Display.getDefault();
  shell = new Shell(display);
  shell.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
  createContents();
  shell.open();
  shell.layout();
  
  while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
   if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
    display.sleep();
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Also, are you using (Windows) 32 or 64 bit? Also, where did you download your package `org.eclipse.swt.*` (if you don't have eclipse)? I don't know what could be going wrong. If I were you I would copy and paste my code into a project called test and see if that works. Then, familiarize yourself with how it works, and redo your project (but luckily you have most of it done)