# How to customize the background color of controls for entering Boolean values generated by EMFForms?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-emf, emf

I have an EMF model, from which I generated UI form and embedded it into a wizard.

The check boxes appear with white background (see below) and it doesn't look nice.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I change the background color of the check box (avoid the white strip) ?

I tried to use `BooleanControlSWTRenderer` sub-class (see below), but it didn't work.

```
public class MyRenderer extends BooleanControlSWTRenderer {

    @Override
    protected Control createSWTControl(Composite parent, Setting setting) {


        final Button check = new Button(parent, SWT.CHECK);
        check.setForeground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
        check.setData(CUSTOM_VARIANT, "org_eclipse_emf_ecp_control_boolean"); //$NON-NLS-1$

        return check;

    }
}
```

**Update 1 (05.11.2014 17:12 MSK):** Calling `check.setBackground(null)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188687/how-to-make-label-backgrounds-transparent-in-swt?rq=1) also doesn't work.

**Update 2 (05.11.2014 17:34 MSK):** Modifying the code to this

```
@Override
protected Control createSWTControl(Composite parent, Setting setting) {
    Button check = new Button(parent, SWT.CHECK);

    check.setBackground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
    parent.setBackground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
    parent.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);

    check.setData(CUSTOM_VARIANT, "org_eclipse_emf_ecp_control_boolean"); //$NON-NLS-1$

    return check;

}
```

results in the following view.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: `setBackground` rather than `setForeground` should work.

Comment: That was a typo. When I change it back to `setBackground` I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you need:

```
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class MyRenderer extends BooleanControlSWTRenderer {

    @Override
    protected Control createSWTControl(final Composite parent, Setting setting) {
        final Button check = new Button(parent, SWT.CHECK);
        check.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            @Override
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent arg0) {
                check.setBackground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
            }
        });
        return check;

    }
}
```

The difference to your `MyRenderer` is here we use an additinal workaround and add a paint listener [due to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312102/changing-org-eclipse-swt-widgets-background-color-in-windows).

I tried it already and it works [see this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcgOP.jpg).